# Adding an user to the repository with read access for specific directories

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

I have a repository on the bitbucket website. All of my website is into that repository. Now I want to hire a new programmer for the project. So I have to add him to the repository.

I want to share only few directories of the project with him, not the whole project. In other word, I want to give him read (or maybe write) access to some specific files and folders.

Is doing that possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, access control can only be done on an entire repository. Which files go where into which directory is all decided inside the repository data.

You could create a new repository, containing only the directories that you would want to share and the use that as a submodule for your main repository though of course.